# IntelliJ + jgitver-maven-plugin - Can't find implementations in multi-module

Tags: intellij-idea, jgitver

- IntelliJ 2022.2.1
- jgitver-maven-plugin 1.9.0

In my maven project I have the following with an interface in one module and implementation in another. It all works fine and builds from command line.

```
parent
  |____ spec
  |       |____MyInterface.java
  |
  |____ impl
          |____MyInterfaceImpl.java
```

When I right-click MyInterface "Go to -> Implementations" I get "No implementations found".

In MyInterface.impl, where I have `class MyInterface implements MyInterface`, When I ctrl+click on `MyInterface`, it opens and decompile NumberResource.class. I can see in the title bar it's getting the class from maven (which makes sense).

I've tried building with -Djgitver.skip to see if that helps... no it doesn't.

I'm assuming this is the fault of jgitver-maven-plugin as without it works.

Anyone know a workaround? (other than removing the plugin)

Comment: Please try `File | Invalidate caches | mark first two checkboxes | Invalidate and Restart`. If the problem remains, please prepare a [minimal reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) project sample.

Comment: Forgot to add, invalidate caches doesnt help.